# FFMPEG Unable to Decode Quicktime QDMC Stream (No decoder for stream)

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime, decoder

We are using FFMPEG to convert iPhone video to MP4.  This requires an AAC decoder which is not included in any binary distributions of FFMPEG (due to licensing issues).  The solution is to download the FFMPEG source and compile it yourself.  I've done this, apparently incorrectly, as I cannot decode the audio stream.  I am getting this error:

```
/usr/ffmpeg_builds/ffmpeg -y -i /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/uploads/celebs/main/step-2.mov -threads 12 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:v 1000k -refs 6 -coder 1 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -me_range 16 -subq 7 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -trellis 1 -b:a 128k -pass 1 -passlogfile /tmp/ffmpeg-passes57a054ee917c4ahl3t/pass-57a054ee91965 /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/uploads/celebs/main/testing-5.mp4
ffmpeg version N-81827-g81bab10 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264
  libavutil      55. 32.100 / 55. 32.100
  libavcodec     57. 60.100 / 57. 60.100
  libavformat    57. 51.102 / 57. 51.102
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 63.100 /  6. 63.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/domain/public_html/wp-content/uploads/celebs/main/step-2.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 1998-11-04T16:40:13.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:00.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 110 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: svq1 (SVQ1 / 0x31515653), yuv410p, 160x120, 90 kb/s, 7.51 fps, 7.50 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1998-11-04T16:40:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Sorenson Video
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: qdmc (QDMC / 0x434D4451), 44100 Hz, mono (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1998-11-04T16:40:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
No decoder for stream #0:1, filtering impossible
Error opening filters!
```

I suspect that I failed to compile and include the correct codec library when I built FFMPEG.  The problem is I don't know which library I should have built/included.  I haven't found anything that says to decode QDMC audio in FFMPEG you need the XXXXX library.

Here's the complete list of decoders that my build supports:

```
/usr/ffmpeg_builds/ffmpeg -decoders
ffmpeg version N-81827-g81bab10 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264
  libavutil      55. 32.100 / 55. 32.100
  libavcodec     57. 60.100 / 57. 60.100
  libavformat    57. 51.102 / 57. 51.102
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 63.100 /  6. 63.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Decoders:
 V..... = Video
 A..... = Audio
 S..... = Subtitle
 .F.... = Frame-level multithreading
 ..S... = Slice-level multithreading
 ...X.. = Codec is experimental
 ....B. = Supports draw_horiz_band
 .....D = Supports direct rendering method 1
 ------
 V....D 012v                 Uncompressed 4:2:2 10-bit
 V....D 4xm                  4X Movie
 V....D 8bps                 QuickTime 8BPS video
 V....D aasc                 Autodesk RLE
 VF...D aic                  Apple Intermediate Codec
 V....D alias_pix            Alias/Wavefront PIX image
 V....D amv                  AMV Video
 V....D anm                  Deluxe Paint Animation
 V....D ansi                 ASCII/ANSI art
 VF...D apng                 APNG (Animated Portable Network Graphics) image
 V....D asv1                 ASUS V1
 V....D asv2                 ASUS V2
 V....D aura                 Auravision AURA
 V....D aura2                Auravision Aura 2
 V....D avrn                 Avid AVI Codec
 V....D avrp                 Avid 1:1 10-bit RGB Packer
 V....D avs                  AVS (Audio Video Standard) video
 V....D avui                 Avid Meridien Uncompressed
 V....D ayuv                 Uncompressed packed MS 4:4:4:4
 V....D bethsoftvid          Bethesda VID video
 V....D bfi                  Brute Force & Ignorance
 V....D binkvideo            Bink video
 V....D bintext              Binary text
 V....D bmp                  BMP (Windows and OS/2 bitmap)
 V....D bmv_video            Discworld II BMV video
 V....D brender_pix          BRender PIX image
 V....D c93                  Interplay C93
 V....D cavs                 Chinese AVS (Audio Video Standard) (AVS1-P2, JiZhun profile)
 V....D cdgraphics           CD Graphics video
 V....D cdxl                 Commodore CDXL video
 VF...D cfhd                 Cineform HD
 V....D cinepak              Cinepak
 V....D cljr                 Cirrus Logic AccuPak
 V....D cllc                 Canopus Lossless Codec
 V....D eacmv                Electronic Arts CMV video (codec cmv)
 V....D cpia                 CPiA video format
 V....D camstudio            CamStudio (codec cscd)
 V....D cyuv                 Creative YUV (CYUV)
 V.S..D dds                  DirectDraw Surface image decoder
 V....D dfa                  Chronomaster DFA
 V.S..D dirac                BBC Dirac VC-2
 VFS..D dnxhd                VC3/DNxHD
 V....D dpx                  DPX (Digital Picture Exchange) image
 V....D dsicinvideo          Delphine Software International CIN video
 V.S..D dvvideo              DV (Digital Video)
 V....D dxa                  Feeble Files/ScummVM DXA
 V....D dxtory               Dxtory
 VFS..D dxv                  Resolume DXV
 V....D escape124            Escape 124
 V....D escape130            Escape 130
 VFS..D exr                  OpenEXR image
 VFS..D ffv1                 FFmpeg video codec #1
 VF..BD ffvhuff              Huffyuv FFmpeg variant
 V.S..D fic                  Mirillis FIC
 V....D flashsv              Flash Screen Video v1
 V....D flashsv2             Flash Screen Video v2
 V....D flic                 Autodesk Animator Flic video
 V...BD flv                  FLV / Sorenson Spark / Sorenson H.263 (Flash Video) (codec flv1)
 VF...D fraps                Fraps
 V....D frwu                 Forward Uncompressed
 V....D g2m                  Go2Meeting
 V....D gif                  GIF (Graphics Interchange Format)
 V....D h261                 H.261
 V...BD h263                 H.263 / H.263-1996, H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2
 V...BD h263i                Intel H.263
 V...BD h263p                H.263 / H.263-1996, H.263+ / H.263-1998 / H.263 version 2
 VFS..D h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
 VFS..D hap                  Vidvox Hap decoder
 VFS..D hevc                 HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding)
 V....D hnm4video            HNM 4 video
 V....D hq_hqa               Canopus HQ/HQA
 V.S..D hqx                  Canopus HQX
 VF..BD huffyuv              Huffyuv / HuffYUV
 V....D idcinvideo           id Quake II CIN video (codec idcin)
 V....D idf                  iCEDraw text
 V....D iff                  IFF ACBM/ANIM/DEEP/ILBM/PBM/RGB8/RGBN (codec iff_ilbm)
 V....D indeo2               Intel Indeo 2
 V....D indeo3               Intel Indeo 3
 V....D indeo4               Intel Indeo Video Interactive 4
 V....D indeo5               Intel Indeo Video Interactive 5
 V....D interplayvideo       Interplay MVE video
 VFS..D jpeg2000             JPEG 2000
 V....D jpegls               JPEG-LS
 V....D jv                   Bitmap Brothers JV video
 V....D kgv1                 Kega Game Video
 V....D kmvc                 Karl Morton's video codec
 VF...D lagarith             Lagarith lossless
 V....D loco                 LOCO
 V....D m101                 Matrox Uncompressed SD
 V....D eamad                Electronic Arts Madcow Video (codec mad)
 VFS..D magicyuv             MagicYUV video
 VF...D mdec                 Sony PlayStation MDEC (Motion DECoder)
 VF...D mimic                Mimic
 V....D mjpeg                MJPEG (Motion JPEG)
 V....D mjpegb               Apple MJPEG-B
 V....D mmvideo              American Laser Games MM Video
 V....D motionpixels         Motion Pixels video
 V.S.BD mpeg1video           MPEG-1 video
 V.S.BD mpeg2video           MPEG-2 video
 V.S.BD mpegvideo            MPEG-1 video (codec mpeg2video)
 VF..BD mpeg4                MPEG-4 part 2
 V....D msa1                 MS ATC Screen
 V...BD msmpeg4v1            MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 1
 V...BD msmpeg4v2            MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 2
 V...BD msmpeg4              MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 3 (codec msmpeg4v3)
 V....D msrle                Microsoft RLE
 V....D mss1                 MS Screen 1
 V....D mss2                 MS Windows Media Video V9 Screen
 V....D msvideo1             Microsoft Video 1
 V....D mszh                 LCL (LossLess Codec Library) MSZH
 V....D mts2                 MS Expression Encoder Screen
 V....D mvc1                 Silicon Graphics Motion Video Compressor 1
 V....D mvc2                 Silicon Graphics Motion Video Compressor 2
 V....D mxpeg                Mobotix MxPEG video
 V....D nuv                  NuppelVideo/RTJPEG
 V....D paf_video            Amazing Studio Packed Animation File Video
 V....D pam                  PAM (Portable AnyMap) image
 V....D pbm                  PBM (Portable BitMap) image
 V....D pcx                  PC Paintbrush PCX image
 V....D pgm                  PGM (Portable GrayMap) image
 V....D pgmyuv               PGMYUV (Portable GrayMap YUV) image
 V....D pictor               Pictor/PC Paint
 VF...D png                  PNG (Portable Network Graphics) image
 V....D ppm                  PPM (Portable PixelMap) image
 V.S..D prores               ProRes
 V.S..D prores_lgpl          Apple ProRes (iCodec Pro) (codec prores)
 V....D ptx                  V.Flash PTX image
 V....D qdraw                Apple QuickDraw
 V....D qpeg                 Q-team QPEG
 V....D qtrle                QuickTime Animation (RLE) video
 V....D r10k                 AJA Kona 10-bit RGB Codec
 V....D r210                 Uncompressed RGB 10-bit
 V..... rawvideo             raw video
 V....D rl2                  RL2 video
 V....D roqvideo             id RoQ video (codec roq)
 V....D rpza                 QuickTime video (RPZA)
 V....D rscc                 innoHeim/Rsupport Screen Capture Codec
 V....D rv10                 RealVideo 1.0
 V....D rv20                 RealVideo 2.0
 VF...D rv30                 RealVideo 3.0
 VF...D rv40                 RealVideo 4.0
 V....D sanm                 LucasArts SANM/Smush video
 V....D screenpresso         Screenpresso
 V....D sgi                  SGI image
 V....D sgirle               Silicon Graphics RLE 8-bit video
 VF...D sheervideo           BitJazz SheerVideo
 V....D smackvid             Smacker video (codec smackvideo)
 V....D smc                  QuickTime Graphics (SMC)
 V..... smvjpeg              SMV JPEG
 V....D snow                 Snow
 V....D sp5x                 Sunplus JPEG (SP5X)
 V....D sunrast              Sun Rasterfile image
 V....D svq1                 Sorenson Vector Quantizer 1 / Sorenson Video 1 / SVQ1
 V...BD svq3                 Sorenson Vector Quantizer 3 / Sorenson Video 3 / SVQ3
 V....D targa                Truevision Targa image
 V....D targa_y216           Pinnacle TARGA CineWave YUV16
 V....D tdsc                 TDSC
 V....D eatgq                Electronic Arts TGQ video (codec tgq)
 V....D eatgv                Electronic Arts TGV video (codec tgv)
 VF..BD theora               Theora
 V....D thp                  Nintendo Gamecube THP video
 V....D tiertexseqvideo      Tiertex Limited SEQ video
 VF...D tiff                 TIFF image
 V....D tmv                  8088flex TMV
 V....D eatqi                Electronic Arts TQI Video (codec tqi)
 V....D truemotion1          Duck TrueMotion 1.0
 V....D truemotion2          Duck TrueMotion 2.0
 V....D truemotion2rt        Duck TrueMotion 2.0 Real Time
 V....D camtasia             TechSmith Screen Capture Codec (codec tscc)
 V....D tscc2                TechSmith Screen Codec 2
 V....D txd                  Renderware TXD (TeXture Dictionary) image
 V....D ultimotion           IBM UltiMotion (codec ulti)
 VF...D utvideo              Ut Video
 V....D v210                 Uncompressed 4:2:2 10-bit
 V....D v210x                Uncompressed 4:2:2 10-bit
 V....D v308                 Uncompressed packed 4:4:4
 V....D v408                 Uncompressed packed QT 4:4:4:4
 V....D v410                 Uncompressed 4:4:4 10-bit
 V....D vb                   Beam Software VB
 VF...D vble                 VBLE Lossless Codec
 V....D vc1                  SMPTE VC-1
 V....D vc1image             Windows Media Video 9 Image v2
 V....D vcr1                 ATI VCR1
 V....D xl                   Miro VideoXL (codec vixl)
 V....D vmdvideo             Sierra VMD video
 V....D vmnc                 VMware Screen Codec / VMware Video
 VF..BD vp3                  On2 VP3
 V....D vp5                  On2 VP5
 V....D vp6                  On2 VP6
 V.S..D vp6a                 On2 VP6 (Flash version, with alpha channel)
 V....D vp6f                 On2 VP6 (Flash version)
 V....D vp7                  On2 VP7
 VFS..D vp8                  On2 VP8
 VF...D vp9                  Google VP9
 VF...D webp                 WebP image
 V...BD wmv1                 Windows Media Video 7
 V...BD wmv2                 Windows Media Video 8
 V....D wmv3                 Windows Media Video 9
 V....D wmv3image            Windows Media Video 9 Image
 V....D wnv1                 Winnov WNV1
 V....D vqavideo             Westwood Studios VQA (Vector Quantized Animation) video (codec ws_vqa)
 V....D xan_wc3              Wing Commander III / Xan
 V....D xan_wc4              Wing Commander IV / Xxan
 V....D xbin                 eXtended BINary text
 V....D xbm                  XBM (X BitMap) image
 V..... xface                X-face image
 V....D xwd                  XWD (X Window Dump) image
 V....D y41p                 Uncompressed YUV 4:1:1 12-bit
 V....D ylc                  YUY2 Lossless Codec
 V..... yop                  Psygnosis YOP Video
 V....D yuv4                 Uncompressed packed 4:2:0
 V....D zerocodec            ZeroCodec Lossless Video
 V....D zlib                 LCL (LossLess Codec Library) ZLIB
 V....D zmbv                 Zip Motion Blocks Video
 A....D 8svx_exp             8SVX exponential
 A....D 8svx_fib             8SVX fibonacci
 A....D aac                  AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
 A....D aac_fixed            AAC (Advanced Audio Coding) (codec aac)
 A....D libfdk_aac           Fraunhofer FDK AAC (codec aac)
 A....D aac_latm             AAC LATM (Advanced Audio Coding LATM syntax)
 A....D ac3                  ATSC A/52A (AC-3)
 A....D ac3_fixed            ATSC A/52A (AC-3) (codec ac3)
 A....D adpcm_4xm            ADPCM 4X Movie
 A....D adpcm_adx            SEGA CRI ADX ADPCM
 A....D adpcm_afc            ADPCM Nintendo Gamecube AFC
 A....D adpcm_aica           ADPCM Yamaha AICA
 A....D adpcm_ct             ADPCM Creative Technology
 A....D adpcm_dtk            ADPCM Nintendo Gamecube DTK
 A....D adpcm_ea             ADPCM Electronic Arts
 A....D adpcm_ea_maxis_xa    ADPCM Electronic Arts Maxis CDROM XA
 A....D adpcm_ea_r1          ADPCM Electronic Arts R1
 A....D adpcm_ea_r2          ADPCM Electronic Arts R2
 A....D adpcm_ea_r3          ADPCM Electronic Arts R3
 A....D adpcm_ea_xas         ADPCM Electronic Arts XAS
 A....D g722                 G.722 ADPCM (codec adpcm_g722)
 A....D g726                 G.726 ADPCM (codec adpcm_g726)
 A....D g726le               G.726 ADPCM little-endian (codec adpcm_g726le)
 A....D adpcm_ima_amv        ADPCM IMA AMV
 A....D adpcm_ima_apc        ADPCM IMA CRYO APC
 A....D adpcm_ima_dat4       ADPCM IMA Eurocom DAT4
 A....D adpcm_ima_dk3        ADPCM IMA Duck DK3
 A....D adpcm_ima_dk4        ADPCM IMA Duck DK4
 A....D adpcm_ima_ea_eacs    ADPCM IMA Electronic Arts EACS
 A....D adpcm_ima_ea_sead    ADPCM IMA Electronic Arts SEAD
 A....D adpcm_ima_iss        ADPCM IMA Funcom ISS
 A....D adpcm_ima_oki        ADPCM IMA Dialogic OKI
 A....D adpcm_ima_qt         ADPCM IMA QuickTime
 A....D adpcm_ima_rad        ADPCM IMA Radical
 A....D adpcm_ima_smjpeg     ADPCM IMA Loki SDL MJPEG
 A....D adpcm_ima_wav        ADPCM IMA WAV
 A....D adpcm_ima_ws         ADPCM IMA Westwood
 A....D adpcm_ms             ADPCM Microsoft
 A....D adpcm_mtaf           ADPCM MTAF
 A....D adpcm_psx            ADPCM Playstation
 A....D adpcm_sbpro_2        ADPCM Sound Blaster Pro 2-bit
 A....D adpcm_sbpro_3        ADPCM Sound Blaster Pro 2.6-bit
 A....D adpcm_sbpro_4        ADPCM Sound Blaster Pro 4-bit
 A....D adpcm_swf            ADPCM Shockwave Flash
 A....D adpcm_thp            ADPCM Nintendo THP
 A....D adpcm_thp_le         ADPCM Nintendo THP (little-endian)
 A....D adpcm_vima           LucasArts VIMA audio
 A....D adpcm_xa             ADPCM CDROM XA
 A....D adpcm_yamaha         ADPCM Yamaha
 AF...D alac                 ALAC (Apple Lossless Audio Codec)
 A....D amrnb                AMR-NB (Adaptive Multi-Rate NarrowBand) (codec amr_nb)
 A....D amrwb                AMR-WB (Adaptive Multi-Rate WideBand) (codec amr_wb)
 A....D ape                  Monkey's Audio
 A....D atrac1               ATRAC1 (Adaptive TRansform Acoustic Coding)
 A....D atrac3               ATRAC3 (Adaptive TRansform Acoustic Coding 3)
 A....D atrac3plus           ATRAC3+ (Adaptive TRansform Acoustic Coding 3+) (codec atrac3p)
 A....D on2avc               On2 Audio for Video Codec (codec avc)
 A....D binkaudio_dct        Bink Audio (DCT)
 A....D binkaudio_rdft       Bink Audio (RDFT)
 A....D bmv_audio            Discworld II BMV audio
 A....D comfortnoise         RFC 3389 comfort noise generator
 A....D cook                 Cook / Cooker / Gecko (RealAudio G2)
 A..... dsd_lsbf             DSD (Direct Stream Digital), least significant bit first
 A..... dsd_lsbf_planar      DSD (Direct Stream Digital), least significant bit first, planar
 A..... dsd_msbf             DSD (Direct Stream Digital), most significant bit first
 A..... dsd_msbf_planar      DSD (Direct Stream Digital), most significant bit first, planar
 A....D dsicinaudio          Delphine Software International CIN audio
 A....D dss_sp               Digital Speech Standard - Standard Play mode (DSS SP)
 A....D dst                  DST (Digital Stream Transfer)
 A....D dca                  DCA (DTS Coherent Acoustics) (codec dts)
 A....D dvaudio              Ulead DV Audio
 A....D eac3                 ATSC A/52B (AC-3, E-AC-3)
 A....D evrc                 EVRC (Enhanced Variable Rate Codec)
 AF...D flac                 FLAC (Free Lossless Audio Codec)
 A....D g723_1               G.723.1
 A....D g729                 G.729
 A....D gsm                  GSM
 A....D gsm_ms               GSM Microsoft variant
 A....D iac                  IAC (Indeo Audio Coder)
 A....D imc                  IMC (Intel Music Coder)
 A....D interplay_dpcm       DPCM Interplay
 A....D interplayacm         Interplay ACM
 A....D mace3                MACE (Macintosh Audio Compression/Expansion) 3:1
 A....D mace6                MACE (Macintosh Audio Compression/Expansion) 6:1
 A....D metasound            Voxware MetaSound
 A....D mlp                  MLP (Meridian Lossless Packing)
 A....D mp1                  MP1 (MPEG audio layer 1)
 A....D mp1float             MP1 (MPEG audio layer 1) (codec mp1)
 A....D mp2                  MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2)
 A....D mp2float             MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2) (codec mp2)
 A....D mp3                  MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 A....D mp3float             MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) (codec mp3)
 A....D mp3adu               ADU (Application Data Unit) MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 A....D mp3adufloat          ADU (Application Data Unit) MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) (codec mp3adu)
 A....D mp3on4               MP3onMP4
 A....D mp3on4float          MP3onMP4 (codec mp3on4)
 A....D als                  MPEG-4 Audio Lossless Coding (ALS) (codec mp4als)
 A....D mpc7                 Musepack SV7 (codec musepack7)
 A....D mpc8                 Musepack SV8 (codec musepack8)
 A....D nellymoser           Nellymoser Asao
 A....D opus                 Opus
 A....D paf_audio            Amazing Studio Packed Animation File Audio
 A....D pcm_alaw             PCM A-law / G.711 A-law
 A....D pcm_bluray           PCM signed 16|20|24-bit big-endian for Blu-ray media
 A....D pcm_dvd              PCM signed 16|20|24-bit big-endian for DVD media
 A....D pcm_f32be            PCM 32-bit floating point big-endian
 A....D pcm_f32le            PCM 32-bit floating point little-endian
 A....D pcm_f64be            PCM 64-bit floating point big-endian
 A....D pcm_f64le            PCM 64-bit floating point little-endian
 A....D pcm_lxf              PCM signed 20-bit little-endian planar
 A....D pcm_mulaw            PCM mu-law / G.711 mu-law
 A....D pcm_s16be            PCM signed 16-bit big-endian
 A....D pcm_s16be_planar     PCM signed 16-bit big-endian planar
 A....D pcm_s16le            PCM signed 16-bit little-endian
 A....D pcm_s16le_planar     PCM signed 16-bit little-endian planar
 A....D pcm_s24be            PCM signed 24-bit big-endian
 A....D pcm_s24daud          PCM D-Cinema audio signed 24-bit
 A....D pcm_s24le            PCM signed 24-bit little-endian
 A....D pcm_s24le_planar     PCM signed 24-bit little-endian planar
 A....D pcm_s32be            PCM signed 32-bit big-endian
 A....D pcm_s32le            PCM signed 32-bit little-endian
 A....D pcm_s32le_planar     PCM signed 32-bit little-endian planar
 A....D pcm_s64be            PCM signed 64-bit big-endian
 A....D pcm_s64le            PCM signed 64-bit little-endian
 A....D pcm_s8               PCM signed 8-bit
 A....D pcm_s8_planar        PCM signed 8-bit planar
 A....D pcm_u16be            PCM unsigned 16-bit big-endian
 A....D pcm_u16le            PCM unsigned 16-bit little-endian
 A....D pcm_u24be            PCM unsigned 24-bit big-endian
 A....D pcm_u24le            PCM unsigned 24-bit little-endian
 A....D pcm_u32be            PCM unsigned 32-bit big-endian
 A....D pcm_u32le            PCM unsigned 32-bit little-endian
 A....D pcm_u8               PCM unsigned 8-bit
 A....D pcm_zork             PCM Zork
 A....D qcelp                QCELP / PureVoice
 A....D qdm2                 QDesign Music Codec 2
 A....D real_144             RealAudio 1.0 (14.4K) (codec ra_144)
 A....D real_288             RealAudio 2.0 (28.8K) (codec ra_288)
 A....D ralf                 RealAudio Lossless
 A....D roq_dpcm             DPCM id RoQ
 A....D s302m                SMPTE 302M
 A....D sdx2_dpcm            DPCM Squareroot-Delta-Exact
 A....D shorten              Shorten
 A....D sipr                 RealAudio SIPR / ACELP.NET
 A....D smackaud             Smacker audio (codec smackaudio)
 A....D sol_dpcm             DPCM Sol
 A..X.D sonic                Sonic
 AF...D tak                  TAK (Tom's lossless Audio Kompressor)
 A....D truehd               TrueHD
 A....D truespeech           DSP Group TrueSpeech
 AF...D tta                  TTA (True Audio)
 A....D twinvq               VQF TwinVQ
 A....D vmdaudio             Sierra VMD audio
 A....D vorbis               Vorbis
 A....D wavesynth            Wave synthesis pseudo-codec
 AF...D wavpack              WavPack
 A....D ws_snd1              Westwood Audio (SND1) (codec westwood_snd1)
 A....D wmalossless          Windows Media Audio Lossless
 A....D wmapro               Windows Media Audio 9 Professional
 A....D wmav1                Windows Media Audio 1
 A....D wmav2                Windows Media Audio 2
 A....D wmavoice             Windows Media Audio Voice
 A....D xan_dpcm             DPCM Xan
 A....D xma1                 Xbox Media Audio 1
 A....D xma2                 Xbox Media Audio 2
 S..... ssa                  ASS (Advanced SubStation Alpha) subtitle (codec ass)
 S..... ass                  ASS (Advanced SubStation Alpha) subtitle
 S..... dvbsub               DVB subtitles (codec dvb_subtitle)
 S..... dvdsub               DVD subtitles (codec dvd_subtitle)
 S..... cc_dec               Closed Caption (EIA-608 / CEA-708) Decoder (codec eia_608)
 S..... pgssub               HDMV Presentation Graphic Stream subtitles (codec hdmv_pgs_subtitle)
 S..... jacosub              JACOsub subtitle
 S..... microdvd             MicroDVD subtitle
 S..... mov_text             3GPP Timed Text subtitle
 S..... mpl2                 MPL2 subtitle
 S..... pjs                  PJS subtitle
 S..... realtext             RealText subtitle
 S..... sami                 SAMI subtitle
 S..... stl                  Spruce subtitle format
 S..... srt                  SubRip subtitle (codec subrip)
 S..... subrip               SubRip subtitle
 S..... subviewer            SubViewer subtitle
 S..... subviewer1           SubViewer1 subtitle
 S..... text                 Raw text subtitle
 S..... vplayer              VPlayer subtitle
 S..... webvtt               WebVTT subtitle
 S..... xsub                 XSUB
```

Any idea what I did wrong when building FFMPEG?

Here's a link to the video file that caused the problem: [step-2.mov](https://1drv.ms/v/s!Aln8SgBjSZM-gZl0qe4N22-NGdhgwA)

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Yes, I felt that I was on the border between the two sites.  There are a lot of Q&A here on the subject and I think my problem is related to my build of FFMPEG from the source, which I think puts the question in SO.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I added the video file that illustrates my problem.  It's 825K.

Comment: You need to build with AudioToolbox enabled. This implies QDMC is only supported on macOS/iOS. (How I know this: [the only place `AV_CODEC_ID_QDMC` is supported in libavcodec is in `audiotoolboxdec.c`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AV_CODEC_ID_QDMC))

Comment: @Cornstalks I recompiled ffmpeg with this configuration: `./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --pkg-config-flags="--static" --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264` and then tried again and got the same error.  Enabling Audio Toolbox did not appear to resolve my problem.

Comment: @mbmast: Are you sure Audio Toolbox was really enabled? Are you compiling on and for macOS? `--enable-audiotoolbox` doesn't actually do anything. AudioToolbox is automatically enabled if it's available. Check your `config.log` file. It runs a `check_header AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h` test; if the `gcc` invocation for that test produces an error, AudioToolbox is disabled.

Comment: @Cornstalks Sure enough `check_header AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h` produces: `error: AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h: No such file or directory`.  Any suggestions for fixing this?  I'm compiling on and for CentOS.

Comment: Like I said in my very first comment, AudioToolbox is only available on iOS and macOS. [AudioToolbox is a framework created by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox), and it's only available in Apple's operating systems.

Comment: FFMPEG is not an Apple product and if AudioToolbox is included in the FFMPEG source, then that would imply that the build scripts know to not build the AudioToolbox components if the build is not taking place on an Apple OS, is that right?  And more generally, how would you convert a video file (to MP4 for example) whose audio was encoded with QDMC on a non-Apple machine running a non-Apple OS (like I'm doing on CentOS)?

Comment: AudioToolbox isn't included in FFmpeg. FFmpeg just makes API calls to AudioToolbox, just like it does with any other third party library. FFmpeg doesn't enable its usage of AudioToolbox if the configure test fails (the very test we talked about earlier). To put it frankly: FFmpeg can't transcode QDMC on a non-Apple OS. You might be able to transmux (from one container format to another, e.g. Matroska to MP4), but you won't be able to transcode (from one audio codec to another, e.g. QDMC to AAC).

Comment: Not even [quicktime4linux](http://heroinewarrior.com/quicktime.php) seems to support it: `av_log(avctx, AV_LOG_ERROR, "stream is QDMC version 1, which is not supported\n");`, which is my go-to for weird Apple stuff.

Comment: @Cornstalks If you provide a short summary of your comments as an answer, I'll accept the answer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### FFmpeg version 3.3 and above

QDMC is supported by both AudioToolbox (Apple OSes only) and FFmpeg's native QDMC decoder.

To use FFmpeg's native QDMC decoder, use decoder strings `qdmc` (or `qdm2` for version 2) (e.g., `-c:a qdmc`).

To use the AudioToolbox QDMC decoder, use decoder strings `qdmc_at` (or `qdm2_at` for version 2) (e.g., `-c:a qdmc_at`).

[Go give Mulvya a +1 for pointing out the new QDMC decoder that Paul B Mahol added to FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41548004/1287251).

---

#### FFmpeg version 3.2.x and below

[FFmpeg supports decoding QDMC](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/dcdf69561fde475f2d99573174eb5ae54e3052de/libavcodec/audiotoolboxdec.c#L624), but only through the third party framework named [AudioToolbox](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox). AudioToolbox is created by Apple and is only available on Apple operating systems (iOS, macOS, and tvOS).

This means that you can't decode QDMC using FFmpeg, since you're using CentOS.

Answer (score 2):

A native QDMC decoder was [added](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=patch;h=90ac9f4094afc2aa7ee64a7b02df8fb05cbd7d8a) to FFmpeg on 7th Jan 2017. With that, you should be able to decode on any platform.